# PHP regex to parse mailto

Tags: php, regex

I have a following html source string:

```
<a href="mailto:abcd@test.com?body=This%20is%20the%20body%20-123-&subject=Subject%20Text&Content-Type=text/plain">Reply To Post</a>
```

From the above string I want to extract:

1. Email address that is the part after mailto: and before ?
2. Body
3. Subject

What can I try?

Answer (score 2):

You would need not need regex for the second part. [It can be parsed as a query string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), IMO.

Something like: (`$s` is the value of `href` in the following code)

```
preg_match("/mailto:(.*?)\?(.*)/",$s,$matches);

echo "Email:" . $matches[1] . "\n";
parse_str($matches[2],$output);
echo "Body: " . $output['body'] . "\n";
echo "Subject: " . $output['subject'] . "\n";
```

Actually, if you are sure the string appears in the exact same fashion, you could take the substring from the offset of index of ":" up to the index of "?", too.

Comment: The `>>` aren't part of the real string (I got the string before the edit). Those are just there due to Stack Overflow's quote markup screwing up. Trying to fix that.

Comment: Yep, fine. Although I wouldn't work with indices here. One more thing for you to fix: You forgot the case where there are no params at all (in case that might happen).

Answer (score 2):

This will assume you only a single mailto link:

```
// $str will be your string content from the question
if (preg_match('/"mailto:([^"]+?)/', $str, $matches) && false !== ($info = parse_url($matches[1]))) {
        $emailAddress = $info['path'];
        $emailParameters = array();
        if (isset($info['query'])) {
                parse_str($info['query'], $emailParameters);
        }
        var_dump($emailAddress, $emailParameters);
}
```

It matches from the `"mailto:` to the first end quote and uses `parse_url` to do the rest.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Using `parse_url()` is a lot easier than reinventing the wheel here, although `parse_str()` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it in PHP, but it works fine in [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/):

`"mailto:([\w%.+-]+?@[\w.-]+?)(?:[?&](?:body=(.*?)|subject=(.*?)|[\w-]+=.*?))+?"`

This should result in the following capture groups:

- 1: email address
- 2: body
- 3: subject

You might want to do some more intensive testing though, as I'm not sure whether I've got all valid mail addresses.

Comment: Regex is an overdose, IMO. The string in the question looks like it can be parsed as a query string. Check my answer..

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$m = preg_match("/mailto:(.+?)\?/");
```

it matches the word `mailto` followed by a colon, followed by a capturing group (parenthesis) which contains any character `.` one or more times `+` un-greedily (? - it will make the capture as short as possible) followed by a (escaped) question mark (`\?`)

Comment: The pattern only captures the email, not the test that OP asked for.